# mysql query issue - generating a reorder report

Tags: mysql

i am working on the following query:-

```
SELECT group,item,buffer,stock,(stock-buffer) AS shortexcess
FROM stkmain, stkbalance, stkbuffer
WHERE stkmain.item = stkbalance.item
AND stkmain.item = stkbuffer.item
```

this query works fine. i want to add another coloumn of sales coming from 'sale' table. the revised query is:-

```
SELECT group,item,buffer,stock,(stock-buffer) AS shortexcess, quantity
FROM stkmain, stkbalance, stkbuffer, sale
WHERE stkmain.item = stkbalance.item
AND stkmain.item = stkbuffer.item
AND stkmain.item = sale.item
```

the problem with this query is that it shows only those rows that are appearing in the sale table and not all the rows of the stkmain table.
kindly advise me how should i rectify this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Left Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) on sktmain to get all rows of sktmain.

```
SELECT group,item,buffer,stock,(stock-buffer) AS shortexcess, quantity
FROM stkmain
LEFT OUTER JOIN stkbalance ON stkmain.item = stkbalance.item
...
```

Comment: @cularisthanks. also now the total rows showing is more than the total no of items. probably because the sale table consists items more than once. how do i get the total sales for a particular item so that the query shows distinct items. the concept for this is to generate a reorder report with item quantities in stock, buffer quantities and sales of those particular items ,if any

Comment: got it. just changed the quantity to sum(quantity) and added the group by item and got it right. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `group`, item,buffer, stock, stock-buffer AS shortexcess 
FROM stkmain
JOIN stkbalance ON skmain.item = stkbalance.item
JOIN stkbuffer ON stkmain.item = stkbuffer.item
OUTER JOIN sale ON stkmain.item = sale.item
```

Group is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) and should be escaped by backticks.